# Sort files sorting the content

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to sort some files sorting alphabetically the content. After that I need to read the files in that order.

1.txt:

```
c
```

2.txt:

```
a
```

3.txt:

```
b
```

I tried to use arrays to handle the file's content and then use `Array.Sort()`, but then I can't read the files correctly.

Maybe there is any way to identify the value's file, after sorting the array.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you assuming that every file contains only one char? Or should it be sorted by it's first byte? Sometimes it is utterly refreshing with what sort of requirements people on StackOverflow come up. Maybe some background on this task is of interest.

Comment: _Maybe there is any way to identify the value's file, after sorting the array_ - Yes, keep both value and file in same object

Comment: @Clijsters No, all the files will have multiple lines, this case I just read one line, that line can have multiple chars.

Comment: @JoãoFerreira Do you want to put "a" into file 1.txt, "b" into 2.txt, and "c" into 3.txt?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, they are already there. I want to read those files in the correct order, and to do that I need to sort those strings alphabetically.

Example, I would need to read the files in this order: 2.txt ; 3.txt ; 1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort files by content then you you have to actually read the content. The sorting would be done like any other sort, e.g.

```vb
Dim sortedFilePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "*txt").
                                OrderBy(Function(filePath) File.ReadLines(filePath).First()).
                                ToArray()
```

That will give you an array of the paths of all text files in your Documents folder, sorted by the first line of the file.